# Can you reuse if statements? Program loops to only first if loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, methods, user-input

This program is made to calculate the hypotenuse of a triangle by taking values of sides A and B. If the program is run, it offers 4 choices to the user, and nothing will happen until the user enters either A,B,C, or Q.  Lets say the user enters A, it allows the user to enter the value of side A, and it will return to the 4 main choices.  Problem is, when the user enters A,B,C, or Q, it just loops to ask for side A again.  Below is the code I have currently.  How do I make it so it doesn't only accept value A?  Thanks

```
public class Newest_Exercise_1 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {    
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         char letter;
         int valueOfA;
         int valueOfB;
         double hypotenuse;


         Boolean loop =true;

         letter = GettingUserInput(input);
            System.out.println("value of letter: " +letter);

         while(loop){
         if(letter=='A' || letter =='a'){
                valueOfA = InputWasA();
                System.out.println(valueOfA);
                letter = GettingUserInput(input);


         }
         if(letter=='B' || letter =='b'){
                valueOfB = InputWasB();
                System.out.println(valueOfB);
                letter = GettingUserInput(input);

         }

         if(letter=='C' || letter =='c'){
                System.out.println("made it to C");
                hypotenuse = Math.sqrt((valueOfA*valueOfA)+(valueOfB*valueOfB));
                System.out.println("Hypotenuse is: "+hypotenuse);
                letter = GettingUserInput(input);


         }
         if(letter=='Q' || letter =='q'){
                System.out.println("made it to Q");
                System.out.println("Program Closed");
                System.exit(0);
         }  
         }
     }

     public static char GettingUserInput(Scanner input){


            System.out.println("A-Enter value of side A");
            System.out.println("B-Enter value of side B");
            System.out.println("C-Calculate");
            System.out.println("Q-Quit the program");

            String s = input.next();
            System.out.println("value of s: "+s);
            char letter = s.charAt(0);

            while(letter != 'A' && letter != 'a' && letter != 'B' && letter != 'b' && letter != 'C' && letter != 'c' && letter != 'Q' && letter != 'q'){
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, Please try again");
                System.out.println("A-Enter value of side A");
                System.out.println("B-Enter value of side B");
                System.out.println("C-Calculate");
                System.out.println("Q-Quit the program");
                s = input.next();
                letter = s.charAt(0);
            }


        return letter; 
     }

     public static int InputWasA(){
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         Boolean loop1 = true;
         int valueOfA = 0;

         while(loop1){
             try{
                 System.out.println("Enter value of side A");
                 valueOfA=input.nextInt();
                 loop1 = false;
             }
             catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println("That was not an integer!");
                 input.next();
             }

         }
         return valueOfA;
     }

     public static int InputWasB(){
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         Boolean loop2 = true;
         int valueOfB = 0;

         while(loop2){
             try{
                 System.out.println("Enter value of side B");
                 valueOfB=input.nextInt();
                 loop2 = false;
             }
             catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println("That was not an integer!");
                 input.next();
             }

         }
         return valueOfB;
     }

     public static void InputWasC(){
            System.out.println("Made it to InputWasC!");
     }





}
```

Comment: What input are you giving?

Comment: see my update. they are intialized in the correct spot. but it seems like they arent being assigned

Comment: You need to init you valueOfA and valueOfB first to 0 or -1. then it will work. I've tested it.

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but you don't need to capitalise `boolean`

Comment: @Zac, nope not at all. but notice that there is a difference in those two types -- `boolean` and `Boolean` as i understand it are _not_ the same thing.

Comment: @Chief, If I've answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I have to ask, what's the point of InputWasA() and InputwasB()? How are they even slightly different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only executing `letter = GettingUserInput(input)` once, so of course `letter` will be the same value forever.

So:

- Move this line *inside* the loop at the start
- Don't repeat it anywhere else - it gets run now at the top of every iteration
- and scrap the `loop` variable too, just use `true`

Make the code look like:

```
while (true) {
    letter = GettingUserInput(input);
    System.out.println("value of letter: " + letter);

    if (letter=='A' || letter =='a') {
        valueOfA = InputWasA();
        System.out.println(valueOfA);
    }

    // etc
```

I have resisted suggesting other improvements, keeping just to the one causing the stated problem, however...

Since your loop has:

- An initial state (read letter)
- A termination test (not a "q")
- An iterative operation (read another letter)

it is clearest and best coded as a `for` loop. Also, to avoid all those dual case tests, the `GettingUserInput()` method should only return lowercase letters, ie its last line should be:

```
return Character.toLowerCase(letter);
```

Given that change, here's how I believe your loop should look:

```
for (char letter = GettingUserInput(input); letter != 'q'; letter = GettingUserInput(input)) {
    if (letter =='a') {
        valueOfA = InputWasA();
        System.out.println(valueOfA);
     }

     if (letter =='b') {
         valueOfB = InputWasB();
         System.out.println(valueOfB);
     }

     if (letter =='c') {
         System.out.println("made it to C");
         hypotenuse = Math.sqrt((valueOfA*valueOfA)+(valueOfB*valueOfB));
         System.out.println("Hypotenuse is: "+hypotenuse);
     }
}

System.out.println("Program Closed");
```

Note how the code for letter `q` is simply whatever follows the loop.

Comment: You missed the calls inside the loop didn't you? he's not assigning the values in subsequent calls.

Comment: Why even bother with true or making it the first line in the loop? it would make far more sense to say `while(  (letter = Character.toLowerCase(GettingUserInput())) != 'q') ... ` in this case. then you check for letter equal to 'a', 'b', or 'c', perform those actions, or continue the loop otherwise. if its 'q' then the loop ends and its over.

Comment: @richard the reason is *readability*; cramming the input read and the comparison into one expression serves only to obfuscate the logic. There are many other improvements that could be made, but I thought using `while (true)` worth mentioning because it's much clearer and is a  common idiom

Comment: You're right it's not as readable as `while (true)` But its more robust and less risk for an infinite loop. I'm not a fan of that idiom for reasons: it's lazy, it defeats the purpose of the conditional, and absolutely _requires_ a break statement which is still based on an actual condition to name a few. Using `while(true)` doesn't obfuscate any of the while logic it's true -- it does, however, obfuscate the real logic behind ending the loop from the loop itself. The only time I think its ok is in a server waiting for connections but even then you need a way to break out and exit cleanly.

Comment: @richard see updated answer for how I think the loop should be coded and why

Comment: See, that's an out of the norm use of a for loop and a much better implementation because it explicitly says what it is going to do. It's readable, consise, and performs the task of reading input from a user waiting to terminate on a sentinel value and performing work the needed of the application. Its also a reduction in the loop's code or the amount of instructions per iteration. It's awesome! You are indeed more well versed than I in the art.